# why this map reduce Promises array does not work, but just reducing it does?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, sequence, es6-promise

Imagine you have an async process which is a cascade of n async steps:

```
function step1(item){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve('step 1 fort item ' + item);
    });
  });
}

function step2(item){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve('step 2 for item ' + item);
    },1000);
  });
}

function step3(item){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve('step 3 for item ' + item);
    },1000);
  });
}

function processItem(item){
  let steps = [step1, step2, step3];
  return steps.reduce((current, next) => {
    return current.then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      return next(item);
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  },Promise.resolve());
}
```

So, now you have an items array, and you want to process all items applying the function processItem to each of them. But for limitations, all processes must be executed in sequence, one starts when the previous one has finished.

well, if I implement it in this way:

```
let items = [1, 2, 3];
items.map(i => processItem(i)).reduce((p, next) => {
  return p.then(() => {
    return next;
  });
}).then(() => {
  // all finished
});
```

You get this output:

```
step 1 for item 1
step 1 for item 2
step 1 for item 3
step 2 for item 1
step 2 for item 2
step 2 for item 3
step 3 for item 1
step 3 for item 2
step 3 for item 3
```

and only takes 3 seconds, not 9 as expected.

Meanwhile if you implement it avoiding  the map step, you get the expected result:

```
let items = [1, 2, 3];
items.reduce((promise, nextItem) => {
  return promise.then(() => {
    return processItem(nextItem);
  });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(() => {
  // all finished
});
```

The result:

```
step 1 for item 1
step 2 for item 1
step 3 for item 1
step 1 for item 2
step 2 for item 2
step 3 for item 2
step 1 for item 3
step 2 for item 3
step 3 for item 3
```

And takes the 9 seconds expected.

Why is happening this? I thought that when you map a promise returning function to an array, you get an array of promises, so, first and seconds arguments of the reduce anonymous function are promises, and you could act as I did in the first example above. I'm a little bit confused with that.

Comment: In your `.map` example you are immediately invoking `processItem` on each `i` without waiting for each to complete and assigning the return value of the method to the item in the _Array_ so yes you have an _Array_ of _Promises_ but each of these promises is not chained, in the `.reduce` example you are setting up a single chain of _Promises_

Comment: @PaulS. So, what would be the best way to map to each array item the processItem function without calling it immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map` is invoking the *function* passed into it, if you don't want `processItem` to be invoked at this step, you need this to be wrapped again, i.e.

```
let items = [1, 2, 3];
items.map(i => () => processItem(i)).reduce(
    (p, next) => p.then(next),
    Promise.resolve()
).then(() => {
    // all finished
});
```

Comment: Or just make it `(p, next) => p.then(next)`

Comment: @Bergi I copied that over (and just added parenthesis) but that does simplify it down really nicely

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Paul S.

Taking your answer as base, I think I prefer to wrap the original `processItem` function:

```
function processItem(item){
  return function(){
    let steps = [step1, step2, step3];
    return steps.reduce((current, next) => {
      return current.then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return next(item);
      }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    },Promise.resolve());
  }
}
```

And then the map.reduce keeps cleaner:

```
items = [1, 2, 3];
items.map(i => processItem(i)).reduce((p, next) => {
    return p.then(() => {
        return next();
    });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(() => {
    // all finished
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't call that function `processItem` any more though, rather use something like `makeItemProcessor`.

Comment: You are right. In fact, that function is a Thunk, so it's like an action creator.